# How to change state in vuex after some time while snackbar closes automatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I created a Snackbar component using vuetify components and imported that snackbar component to some other component. I am sending props from parent to child snackbar component. The snackbar closes automatically after some time. At this point error is coming like "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value".

The snackbar closes automatically after 3 seconds. How to set state false after closing of snackbar.

**Snackbar component**

```
<v-snackbar 
                :timeout="timeout"
                :color="color"
                :top="y === 'top'"
                :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
                :right="x === 'right'"
                :left="x === 'left'"
                :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
                :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
                v-model="snackbar"
            >
                {{ text }}
                <v-btn flat color="pink" @click.native="snackbarClose"><v-icon>{{close}}</v-icon></v-btn>
            </v-snackbar>
```

**props**

```
props: ["snackbar", "y", "x", "mode", "timeout", "color", "close", "text", "submit"],
```

**methods in snackbar component**

```
methods: {
        snackbarClose () {
            this.$store.commit("snackbarClose", false)
            // this.$emit('snackbarClose', false)
        }
    }
```

**Parent component**

```
<Snackbar 
            :close="close"
            :snackbar="snackbarBox"
            :y="y"
            :x="x"
            :mode="mode"
            :timeout="timeout"
            :color="snackbarColor"
            :text="snackbarText"
            :submit="text"
        />
```

**data in parent component**

```
data(){
return{
 y: "top",
      x: "right",
      mode: "multi-line",
      timeout: 3000,
      text: "",
      color: "",
      close: "close",
}
}
```

**importing getters in parent component**

```
 ...mapGetters([ "snackbarBox"])
```

**vuex**
**mutations**

```
snackbarClose: (state, payload) => {
        state.snackbarBox = payload
    },
```

**state**

```
snackbarBox: false,
```

**getters**

```
snackbarBox: state => {
        return state.snackbarBox;
    },
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem preparing a Snackbar component and I used a watcher to change the $state before "timeout" finished. By default, after 6 seconds the snackbar closes but I am using setTimeout with 4 second to modify the State and close it before this 6 seconds.
In my case I am using ts but I think you can use it.

### Snackbar component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-snackbar v-model="snackbarData.show"  :color="snackbarData.color" bottom >
      {{snackbarData.message}} 
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import { Watch, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class SnackBar extends Vue {

@Prop({default:null})    
snackbarData!: Object 

 @Watch("snackbarData.show", { deep: true })
  onShowChanges(value: any) {
    if (value === true) {
      const snackbar: any = {
        show: false,
        message:'',
        color: null, 
     };
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.$store.commit('updateMainSnackbar', snackbar);
      }, 4000)
  } 
  }
}
```

### Stored

This is my object but if you need more properties you should add them.

```js
   mainSnackbar: {
        show: false,
        message: '',
        color: null
    }
```

### Mutation

```js
  updateMainSnackbar (state:any, data: any){
      state.mainSnackbar.show = data.show;
      state.mainSnackbar.message = data.message;
      state.mainSnackbar.color = data.color;
    }
```

### Import and Include the component

Import the component and pass the properties

```html
<template>
   <SnackBar :snackbarData="mainSnackbar" />
</template>

// ----------
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

import SnackBar from "SnackBar.vue"
@Component({
  components: { SnackBar }
})
export default class OurComponent extends Vue {

// Computed

 get mainSnackbar(){
    return this.$store.state.mainSnackbar;
  }
```

### Execute the mutation to active the Snackbar

Call the mutation with the data you want to show in the snackbar. In my case I was using a method.

```js
setSnackBar(){
  const data= {
        show: true,
        message:'The message you want to show',
        color: '#ffff', 
     };
  this.$store.commit('updateMainSnackbar', data);
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you watch `snackbar` in `Snackbar component`?

something like:

```
watch: {
  snackbar: function(newVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
       this.snackbarClose()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no watch